# ERROR Angularjs + Lagom Framework

Tags: angularjs, cors, cross-domain, lagom, http-options-method

OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/api/chat/ 404 (Not Found)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/chat/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Comment: Can not find dependencies for CROSSFilter play Framework. Not working this import: 'import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;' Please help find MAVEN dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter has details on enabling CORS for Play (which is Lagom is built on). To handle the `OPTIONS` you may need to do something like:

```
.withAutoAcl(true)
.withServiceAcls(
  ServiceAcl.methodAndPath(Method.OPTIONS, "/foo")
)
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lagom-framework/dtYN_1Ds4SQ/gT-BGPuCAQAJ is a lagom-framework list discussion thread with more details.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests has an explanation of why your browser is sending an `OPTIONS` request to begin with.

---

The [metadata for the current exact maven artifact which provides CORS for Play](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/filters-helpers_2.12/) is this:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
  <artifactId>filters-helpers_2.12</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>2.6.0-M2</latest>
    <release>2.6.0-M2</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.6.0-M1</version>
      <version>2.6.0-M2</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20170310220437</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. We (some employees at lightbend) recently worked on an experiment and we needed CORS on a Lagom service. See https://github.com/ignasi35/lagom-pet-store/blob/master/pet/src/main/java/Filters.java (Filters.java _must be_ in the default package) and https://github.com/ignasi35/lagom-pet-store/blob/master/build.sbt#L18 is required to import Play's filters.

Comment: Can not find dependencies for CROSSFilter play Framework. Not working this import: 'import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;' Please help find MAVEN dependency

Comment: @VitaliyDenys I’ve added the maven info the answer